# IntelliJ cannot resolve maven plugins

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-ee-8

I am new to Java EE and Maven, so I am not quiet sure which information are needed to see where I made a mistake.

When I right click on my project and got to Maven --> Reload Project
the build tab opens with following errors

```
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.0.0-M1
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
```

[image]

When I hover the maven assembly plugin, the IDE also tells me

```
Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:' not found
```

[image]

When I run mvn clean install -U the build runs just fine without any errors.

Here are my Maven settings
[image]

If I need to any further information please tell me so.

Comment: check this jar is in your computer or not first.

Comment: Do you check the interoperatbility of your IntelliJ version and the Maven plugin. Normally IntelliJ will do it, but sometimes it does not.

Comment: Do you build work on plain command line (not inside IDEA)...

Comment: @khmarbaise no, I build in the IntelliJ Terminal command line

Comment: Please check on plain command line...

Comment: Are there any additional errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: One possible cause is that maven is not able to access the plugins repository. Maven works with plugins, everything is done via plugins, even compile. But the default phases use default plugins that you don't have to configure. I don't know if maven have this default plugins already downloaded or does it the first time. Please post your settings.xml, and look windows network configuration to see if you are behind a proxy.